# Refining an Entity Framework result set using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, search

I'm trying to refine a set of EF results. I have the following line which grabs all entities:

```
var results = context.Referrals.ToList();
```

Which is fine. When I try to conditionally refine the list, I suddenly have an empty list. For example:

```
if (filterByReferrerName)
   results = results.Where(x => x.ReferrerName.Contains("John Doe")).ToList();
```

I know there is an item in that initial list with a ReferrerName of "John Doe", but cannot understand why my result set is suddenly empty after that .Where clause.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: When you do `ToList` to get all data, the latter filter will be done in memory and will be case sensitive. May that be causing your missing data?

Comment: Oops! Apologies Joachim, I wrote some more tests and you were exactly right. I would accept your reply as an answer if it wasn't a comment!

Answer (score 1):

if "ReferrerName" is a complex type on Referral class and you are not using lazy loading you must use eager loading and include that complex type in query, see:

```
var results = 
      context
     .Referrals
     .Include("ReferrerName")
     .Where(x => x.ReferrerName.Contains("John Doe"))
     .ToList();
```

hope it helps.